# xgboost: Sample Weights for Imbalanced Data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a highly unbalanced dataset of 3 classes. To address this, I applied the `sample_weight` array in the XGBClassifier, but I'm not noticing any changes in the modelling results? All of the metrics in the classification report (confusion matrix) are the same. Is there an issue with the implementation?

**The class ratios:**

```
military: 1171 
government: 34852 
other: 20869
```

**Example:**

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer(analyzer=process_text)), # convert strings to integer counts
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), # convert integer counts to weighted TF-IDF scores
    ('classifier', XGBClassifier(sample_weight=compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y_train))) # train on TF-IDF vectors w/ Naive Bayes classifier
])
```

**Sample of Dataset:**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'entity_name': ['UNICEF', 'US Military', 'Ryan Miller'], 
                     'class': ['government', 'military', 'other']})
```

**Classification Report**

[image]

Comment: *"3 classes, highly unbalanced"* is too vague. **What's the class ratio? 96:3:1?** *"I'm not noticing any changes in the modelling results"* is also not specific: show us the results before, and result after. **What [objective](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html?highlight=objective#learning-task-parameters) are you using? And are you using eval_metric `merror`, `mlogloss` or something else?)**. We need you to edit all that into your question (Also, I believe tweaking `scale_pos_weight` and `min_child_weight` only work for two-class/binary)

Comment: See [DataScience.SE : Unbalanced multiclass data with XGBoost](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/unbalanced-multiclass-data-with-xgboost)

Comment: @smci I edited the question w/ more details

Comment: I also saw that thread already. It's what I used to generate the array for the weights

Comment: I was expecting you'd express the class ratio as a ratio. Or, fractions summing to 1.0, or percentages summing to 100%. Anyway the ratio is military: government: other` 1:30:18. Or as percentages 2:61:37%

Comment: Also, please make your code example reproducible, I had to google for the missing `import sklearn.utils.class_weight` to see where `compute_sample_weight('balanced', ...)` came from. What weights does it generate? You can manually define them, try playing around with them yourself. And try setting `min_child_weight` higher, so it requires a few exemplars. Do that experimentation, check before concluding it doesn't work.

Comment: **Use eval_metric=`mlogloss` or `merror`, then post us the results.** You showed us `['precision','recall','f1-score','support']`, but that's supoptimal, or outright broken unless you computed it in a multi-class-aware way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First, most important: **use a multiclass `eval_metric`. `eval_metric=merror` or `mlogloss`**, then post us the results. You showed us `['precision','recall','f1-score','support']`, but that's suboptimal, or outright broken unless you computed them in a multi-class-aware, imbalanced-aware way.
2. Second, you need **weights**. Your class ratio is `military: government: other` 1:30:18, or as percentages 2:61:37%. That's severely imbalanced.

- You can manually set per-class weights with `xgb.DMatrix..., weights)`
- Look inside your pipeline (use print or verbose settings, dump values), don't just blindly rely on boilerplate like `sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight('balanced', ...)` to give you optimal weights.
- Experiment with manually setting per-class weights, starting with `1 : 1/30 : 1/18` and try more extreme values. Reciprocals so the rarer class gets higher weight.
- **Also try setting `min_child_weight` much higher, so it requires a few exemplars (of the minority classes)**. Start with `min_child_weight >= 2`(* weight of rarest class)  and try going higher. Beware of overfitting to the very rare minority class (this is why people use StratifiedKFold crossvalidation, for some protection, but your code isn't using CV).

1. **We can't see your other parameters for xgboost classifier (how many estimators? early stopping on or off? what was learning_rate/eta? etc etc.). Seems like you used the defaults - they'll be terrible**. Or else you're not showing your code. Distrust xgboost's defaults, esp. for multiclass, don't expect xgboost to give good out-of-the-box results. Read the doc and experiment with values.
2. **Do all that experimentation, post your results, check before concluding "it doesn't work".** Don't expect optimal results from out-of-the-box. Distrust or double-check the sklearn util functions, try manual alternatives. (Often, just because sklearn has a function to do something, doesn't mean it's good or best or suitable for all use-cases, like imbalanced multiclass)